# TO_CHAR is not comparing properly in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, to-char

I am using Oracle, and I need to perform some mathematic calculations where I need `TO_CHAR()`.

But it is not comparing the values.

Here is sample below.

```
IF TO_CHAR(V_APP_FAIR_RENT, '99,9999') > TO_CHAR(v_ACT_RENTAMT, '99,9999')
 THEN
 V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := 0;
dbms_output.put_line('Higher Rental premium 0 :' || V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM);
ELSE
V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := v_ACT_RENTAMT / V_AMTINMONTH;
V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM * V_NOOFDAYSINMONTH;
V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM - V_APP_FAIR_RENT;
V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM :=  ROUND(V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM / V_NOOFOPCO);
dbms_output.put_line('Higher rental premium  1 :' || V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM);
END IF;
```

The values for both comparison is below.

`V_APP_FAIR_RENT` = `7455` and `v_ACT_RENTAMT` = `10928`

Technically with the above comparision it should go in IF condition, but actually it goes in ELSE condition.

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why are you using to_char to compare numerical values at all?

Answer (score 2):

If as you say your original columns are strings (why?), and your examples do not appear to include group or decimal characters, then why not use to_number with default formatting to compare the numeric values?

```
IF to_number(V_APP_FAIR_RENT) > to_number(V_ACT_RENTAMT)
THEN
    V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := 0;
    dbms_output.put_line('Higher Rental premium 0 :' || V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM);
ELSE
    V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := v_ACT_RENTAMT / V_AMTINMONTH;
    V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM * V_NOOFDAYSINMONTH;
    V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM := V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM - V_APP_FAIR_RENT;
    V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM :=  ROUND(V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM / V_NOOFOPCO);
    dbms_output.put_line('Higher rental premium  1 :' || V_HIGHER_RENT_PREMIUM);
END IF;
```

Comment: then why convert a string to another string? use to_number so that you can compare the numeric values. i have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so will it consider the decimal point also ?

Comment: Your examples did not include any decimal points. worst case if Oracle doesn't make the conversion automatically, you might need to include a format template in the to_number function call, like `to_number(v_app_fair_rent,'99999.99')`. Why weren't these values stored as numbers in the first place?

Comment: i know I shd have taken `to_number` at first place but that something after changing is not working.. may be it should technically go in ELSE only.. can u help me with that

Comment: You should define these variables as numbers in the first place, rather than worry about constant conversions. You can't do mathematical operations on strings.

Answer (score 0):

as @pmdba said, why are you converting what is already a number(is it?), for comparison?

If you execute the query:

```
select TO_CHAR(7455 , '99,9999'), TO_CHAR(10928, '99,9999') from dual
```

the result is the strings:   "7455"   "1,0928".

One has a thousands separator and the other does not. so you are not comparing numerical values, and the string representation will not work for compare in this case.

If you still are bent on conversion, you need to remove the comma separator:

```
select TO_CHAR(7455 , '999999'), TO_CHAR(10928, '999999') from dual
```

maybe you can edit your question to show how those variables are defined to determine what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But if you remove the comma separator, you're comparing strings so the comparison will be based on alphabetical order not numerical order.  The string '10' comes alphabetically before the string '2'.  Or in this case, the string '10928' comes alphabetically before the string '7455'.